# Solve $C^T A C= aI$ where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $C \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n-1}$ has $n$ orthonormal columns.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $C^T A C= aI$ for some $a\in (0,1)$ where $I_{n-1}$ identity.

- $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is symmetric and positive definite,
- $C \in  \mathbb{R}^{n \times n-1}$ has $n-1$ orthonormal columns (e.g., $C^TC= I_{n-1}$).

**Question:** 
What properties does $A$ have to satisfy?  Can we characterize the class of $A$ that satisfies this?

For example, $A=a I$ is a solution to this, but I think there are more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question title does not match the question body. I suppose that you are solving the problem described in the question body.

Let $C$ be the first $n-1$ columns of a real orthogonal matrix $Q$ and let $A=QBQ^T$. Then
$$
aI_{n-1}=C^TAC=\pmatrix{I_{n-1}&0}B\pmatrix{I_{n-1}\\ 0}.
$$
Hence $B=\pmatrix{aI_{n-1}&v\\ v^T&b}$ and $A=Q \pmatrix{aI_{n-1}&v\\ v^T&b}Q^T$ for some vector $v$ and some scalar $b$. To make $A$ is positive definite, the Schur complement of $aI_{n-1}$ in $B$ must be positive. Hence we need $b-\frac{1}{a}\|v\|^2>0$.

Answer (score 0):

We put :
$$H=C^TAC$$
Then for all $k⩾0$ :
$$H^k=C^TA^kC=a^kI$$
when k go to infinity we obtain :
$$\lim_{k\to \infty}A^k=0$$
And finally this implies that the spectral radius of A is less than 1,
$$C^TAC=aI\ with\  a∈(0,1) ⇒\rho(A)<1$$
Best regards.